# Return titles from page using requests.get and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, anaconda

I am trying to return the teaser titles of all articles on a page. No matter which page I search susing the below code, I receive

**Process finished with exit code 0** and nothing more.

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. I'm usin PyCharm 2016.3.2 and Anaconda3.

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    # User agent to bypass scraping security
    agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'}
    req = requests.get("http://www.zerohedge.com/", agent)

    #req.content = html page source and we are using the html parser
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

    for i in soup.find_all("title teaser-title"):
        print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the tag you want the search and optionally its class. Like this:

```
soup.find_all("h2", class_="title teaser-title")
```

Or use an `cssselector`:

```
soup.select("h2[class='title teaser-title']")
```

Comment: Thanks @Zroq, the class tag (h2) was the part I was missing.